# Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Actions'

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, ngrx

I am new to TypeScript and Visual Studio Code.
I am getting the following Error:

`*[ts] Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'Actions'.`

My code:

action.ts file:

```
  import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
  import { Item } from '../models/list';

  export class AddBookAction implements Action {
      type = ActionTypes.ADD_BOOK;

      constructor(public payload: Item) { }
  }

  export type Actions = AddBookAction;
```

reducer.ts

```
import * as list from 'action';

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: list.Actions): State {

switch (action.type) {
    case list.ActionTypes.LOAD: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: true
      });
    }

    case list.ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS: {
      const books = action.payload // Error here

      return {
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
        ids: books.map(book => book.id)
      };
    }
}
```

Any advice will be very helpful.

Comment: What Typescript version are you using? Is just VSCode throwing that error or is the Typescript compiler complaining as well?

Comment: I get the same error...I use typescript version 2.0.3

Comment: I don't see the error and I'm using TypeScript 2.0.10.

Comment: i am using the typescript version 2.0.3

Comment: Updated to TypeScript 2.0.10 but still getting the same error...

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted looks like it is incomplete, because in *reducer.ts* you are using `list.ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS`, however this is not part of the *action.ts* you posted.

So one guess might be, that in your `LoadSuccessAction` you are missing the `payload`-attirbute - e.g. `public payload: Item`.

Another guess is that you forgot to union the `LoadSuccess`-type in:

```
export type Actions = AddBookAction | LoadSuccessAction;
```

Comment: I was missing the payload item in some Actions, this solved the error, but the payload is not typed. What is the advantage of using `action: list.Actions` insted of just `action: Action`? I don't see any sense if the payload is not typed in both cases...

Comment: The advantage is, that with `list.Actions` you have a defined set of actions that are accepted by your reducer, that enables you to detect type-mismatch errors (or an error like yours) at compile-time instead of at runtime (which would be the case with `action: Action`) - see here for more technical details:  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: I don't get it. In some/most cases reducers want to react also to actions from other reducers to change their state,or sometimes actions don't need a payload. In this way I need to give every Action a payload (which would be overhead in my opinion) + I can't access other reducers Actions... If the payload itself would be typed it would make sense because you could see which properties each payload of the action has while coding / at compile-time.

Comment: You don't _have_ to use that system - it is just a development help, which is used in the ngrx example app - but you could just as well type it  to   action:Action  and it will just work as well, but some codecompletion and typechecking will not be done - it is simply a personal preference.